# Configuration management for 50 users, for source code and documents

Tags: version-control, configuration-management

I am looking for a configuration management product that satisfies these needs:

- I want to be able to store and fetch source code files and documents.
- I want to see the changes made by whom and when in detail.
- I want to be able to see versions clearly.
- I want it to be secure.
- User capacity is about 50 people.

My OS is windows, I have no specific budget on my mind, I am going to store source codes and word documents.

Comment: If Openproject **required** you to install Subversion in 2019, then there is no way choosing it would be right.

Comment: @john I didn't understand, it was my choice to set up openproject with svn, is that bad?

Comment: Subversion is obsolete technology, maybe (sometimes not) good enough to be maintained as legacy, but it shouldn't be used in new installations. If Openproject doesn't support anything other than Subversion, that's a bad smell.

Comment: Hello Deniz, please read https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69/is-tool-x-versus-tool-y-an-on-topic-question to know why A vs B questions are off-topic here.

Comment: I edited the question to make it on-topic. Please also specify your operating system (Linux? Mac? Windows?) and your budget. What kind of documents will you store? For instance movies, or only text files?